# Prevent page from showing after pressing back button

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to prevent my php page from showing content after i log out by pressing back button?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve] to get you started. In this form, your question is too broad. It will get downvoted and you won't receive any help. We're trying to help out, but we can only do so if you provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty the session on sign out first

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
exit;
?>
```

then on the top of each page check if the session is empty then redirect to login page:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
header('Location: index.php');
}
```